# node.js and mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
result = db.query("SELECT user_id "+
  "FROM friends "+
  "WHERE user_id IN "+
    "(SELECT to_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = " + client.user_id + ") "+
    "AND to_id = " + client.user_id);
```

`client.user_id` is 1. checked and confirmed.

This statement has some issues with it. I have a console.log("a") after this line and it wont execute, but if i put a console.log("b"), it is executed.

just running the resulting sql query ie

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM friends 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT to_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1) 
  AND to_id = 1
```

returns one row with `user_id` = 2

a separate node.js program with the query

```
SELECT user_id 
FROM friends 
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT to_id FROM friends WHERE user_id = 1) 
  AND to_id = 1
```

works just fine. which leads me to believe that it probably has to do smthng with client.user_id

any ideas?

UPDATE:

A test with
    client = {user_id: 1}

and the original query in a separate program is working...

Edit: the fundtion where this query is being used.

```
function subscribe_to_friends(client) {
result = db.query("select user_id from friends where user_id IN (select to_id from friends where user_id = " + client.user_id + ") and to_id = " + client.user_id);
}
```

and the function calling this

```
client.on('message', function(msg) {
    if(client.user_id == null) {
        client.user_id = msg.user_id
        subscribe_to_friends(client);
        clients.push(client);
    }
});
```

Comment: What does `console.log(client.user_id)` show the value is?

Comment: it shows 1... which is correct.... Also doing a console.log(the query) gives the desired query.

Comment: is it possible it's console.log() causing the problem if you're using Firefox / IE ?